# Add value to new line in array

Tags: c#, console-application

How can I add a new line to an array? The array is currently empty.

I tried this but it didn't work

```
string[] testarray;
testarray[0] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
testarray[1] = "example text 1";

int i = testarray.Length;
i++;
testarray[i] = "example text 2";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try *initializing* the array with required items:

```
 string[] testarray = new string[] {
   "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
   "example text 1",
   "example text 2",  
 };
```

Or use `List<string>` and `Add` items in *dynamic*:

```
 List<string> testArray = new List<string>();

 testArray.Add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"); 
 testArray.Add("example text 1");

 ...

 testArray.Add("example text 2");
```

If you *insist* on array changing its length in *dynamic*, you have to put something like this (note, array is *not* the collection type designed to change its length):

```
 string[] testarray = new string[0];

 ...

 // recreates testarray with longer Length
 Array.Resize(ref testarray, testarray.Length + 1);
 // put the value at the last cell
 testarray[testarray.Length - 1] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";

 ...
 
 Array.Resize(ref testarray, testarray.Length + 1);

 testarray[testarray.Length - 1] = "example text 1";

 ...
 
 Array.Resize(ref testarray, testarray.Length + 1);

 testarray[testarray.Length - 1] = "example text 2";
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.